# Benefit vs. Harm with haram action

Tags: halal-haram, lying

Salam,

When it comes to a haram action, if the benefits to one’s seen outweigh the harm, would it be permissible? More specifically, if one needs to commit one deceptive/dishonest action and as a result will be in a situation where he or she has more opportunity to succeed and be more religious, would that one action of deception be deemed permissible?

Comment: To me this looks like a question which needs to be specified and treated by example. I'm not sure whether your statement is too vague to give an overall rule or statement.

Comment: I live in the US and am trying to go to college in Jordan—the culture there is more conducive to being able to practice religion more openly and free of judgement and it will be more relaxing as I am around other Muslims. There is a cut-off for the only school I’m able to apply to of an 85%. In my last year of high school, I took a class I thought wasn’t for credit and didn’t pass. Without that class, I am above the cut off. With it, I am below it. I have the opportunity to modify the transcript I’m giving the program, would that be halal because of the many benefits to the one bad action?

Comment: Your comment belongs in your post, comments are meant for clarification. Consider editing your post and adding this information (use the **edit** link).